# Motorola Droid X, Android 2.3.3 list view row divider

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am new to android development and I have a list view that I have used to display images. Each row is a custom row and each cell is also a custom layout.

Everything works fine, but as soon as I tested my code on the Motorola Droid X running android 2.3.3, I could see a white line appear just above every row divider.

I am aware of the listview footer issue with the droid x 2.3.3, and I feel this is also an issue, due to the default list view  layout that it uses.

But I am not able to figure out a way to hide the white line. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Did you do this? http://christianscode.blogspot.com/2012/06/android-motorola-issue-with-listview.html

Comment: Thanks Sherif. If you post this as the answer, I will vote you up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent dead links, if anyone needs help with motorola list views in the future, all you need to do is add this to your list view in XML:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"           
android:overScrollFooter="@null"
```